# How do I keep track of multiple identity columns in a query

Tags: postgresql

I have the following data structure...

```
CREATE TABLE MAIN.ADDRESS(
  ID UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT GEN_RANDOM_UUID() NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS_LINE1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS_LINE2 VARCHAR(100),
  CITY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  STATE VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  ZIP VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE MAIN.PERSON(
  ID UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT GEN_RANDOM_UUID(),
  NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PHONE VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  ADDRESS_ID UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES MAIN.ADDRESS(ID),
);
CREATE TABLE MAIN.STORE(
  ID UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT GEN_RANDOM_UUID(),
  NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PHONE VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  MANAGER_ID UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES MAIN.PERSON(ID),
  ADDRESS_ID UUID REFERENCES MAIN.ADDRESS(ID)
);
```

Now I am writing my Query to insert. The first step (Adding the store manager) works with this query...

```
WITH STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS AS(
  INSERT INTO MAIN.ADDRESS (ADDRESS_LINE1, CITY, STATE, ZIP) 
  VALUES ('4321 Hubbard Ave', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43217')
  RETURNING ID
)
INSERT INTO MAIN.PERSON (NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS_ID)
SELECT 'John Doe','15555555555','jd@gmail.com', ID
FROM STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS;
```

Now I want to Add the store so I thought maybe something like this...

```
DECLARE STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS_ID UUID;
DECLARE STORE_ADDRESS_ID UUID;
DECLARE STORE_MANAGER_PERSON_ID UUID;
WITH STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS AS(
  INSERT INTO MAIN.ADDRESS (ADDRESS_LINE1, CITY, STATE, ZIP) 
  VALUES ('4321 Hubbard Ave', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43217')
  RETURNING ID
)
SELECT ID FROM STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS INTO STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS_ID
WITH STORE_MANAGER AS(
  INSERT INTO MAIN.PERSON (NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS_ID)
  VALUES ('John Doe','15555555555','jd@gmail.com', STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS_ID)
  RETURNING ID
)
SELECT ID FROM STORE_MANAGER INTO STORE_MANAGER_PERSON_ID
WITH STORE_ADDRESS AS(
  INSERT INTO MAIN.ADDRESS (ADDRESS_LINE1, CITY, STATE, ZIP) 
  VALUES ('1234 Main St', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43201')
  RETURNING ID
)
SELECT ID FROM STORE_ADDRESS INTO STORE_ADDRESS_ID
INSERT INTO MAIN.STORE (NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, MANAGER_ID, ADDRESS_ID)
VALUES ('Store 1', '1231231234','a@b.com',STORE_MANAGER_PERSON_ID, STORE_ADDRESS_ID)
```

But it fails with,

```
syntax error at or near "UUID"
name: error
length: 93
severity: ERROR
code: 42601
position: 34
file: scan.l
line: 1087
routine: scanner_yyerror
```

What am I missing? how would I handle something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple CTEs in one query:

```
WITH STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS AS(
  INSERT INTO MAIN.ADDRESS (ADDRESS_LINE1, CITY, STATE, ZIP) 
  VALUES ('4321 Hubbard Ave', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43217')
  RETURNING ID AS STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS_ID
),
STORE_MANAGER AS(
  INSERT INTO MAIN.PERSON (NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS_ID)
  SELECT 'John Doe',
         '15555555555',
         'jd@gmail.com',
         STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS_ID
  FROM STORE_MANAGER_ADDRESS
  RETURNING ID AS STORE_MANAGER_PERSON_ID
),
STORE_ADDRESS AS(
  INSERT INTO MAIN.ADDRESS (ADDRESS_LINE1, CITY, STATE, ZIP) 
  VALUES ('1234 Main St', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43201')
  RETURNING ID AS STORE_ADDRESS_ID
)
INSERT INTO MAIN.STORE (NAME, PHONE, EMAIL, MANAGER_ID, ADDRESS_ID)
SELECT 'Store 1',
       '1231231234',
       'a@b.com',
       STORE_MANAGER.STORE_MANAGER_PERSON_ID,
       STORE.ADDRESS.STORE_ADDRESS_ID
FROM STORE_MANAGER CROSS JOIN STORE ADDRESS;
```